# DirectX 11 transparent blending missing every other texel

Tags: directx, blend

I'm trying to render transparent pixels in directX 11 and I'm not sure if I'm supposed to make a shader or if the blend state does this automatically. 
Earlier I thought it was done automatically but my transparent texture is rendering as a solid color that misses every over texel.
The original texture is (7, 7, 7, 139) and the rendered color is (38, 47, 56, 255).

[image]

[image: enter link description here]

```
blendStateDescription.AlphaToCoverageEnable =                   TRUE;
blendStateDescription.IndependentBlendEnable =                  FALSE;
blendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].BlendEnable =             TRUE;
blendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].BlendOp =                 D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;
blendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].BlendOpAlpha =            D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;
blendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].SrcBlend =                D3D11_BLEND_SRC_ALPHA;
blendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].DestBlend =               D3D11_BLEND_INV_SRC_ALPHA;
blendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].SrcBlendAlpha =           D3D11_BLEND_ONE;
blendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].DestBlendAlpha =          D3D11_BLEND_ZERO;
blendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].RenderTargetWriteMask  =  D3D11_COLOR_WRITE_ENABLE_ALL;
```

pixel shader

```
float4 TexturePixelShader(PixelInputType input) : SV_TARGET {
float4 textureColor;
textureColor = shaderTexture.Sample(SampleType, input.tex);
//discard pink for sprite transparency
if(textureColor.r == 1.0f && textureColor.g == 0.0f && textureColor.b == 1.0f) {
    discard;
}
//set the colour white as the specified pixel colour
if(textureColor.r == 1.0f && textureColor.g == 1.0f && textureColor.b == 1.0f) {
    textureColor = textureColor * pixelColor;
}
return textureColor;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off `AlphaToCoverage`. This should only be used for multi-sampling renderings.

Comment: When I do this the screen goes black but I'm guessing this can be fixed by configuring the blend description. Thanks for the help :D

Comment: yup, fixed it. Just want to say a huge thank you :) I've been at this for an embarrassing length of time. God bless, take care <3